# output de netbeans no puedo hacer click al enlace de linea de error

Tags: logger, netbeans-8.1

35 29/01/2019 17:46:16 INFO  .s.support.ExceptionLoggerPointCut 
    at com.solmit.service.impl.UsuarioServiceImpl.listarUsuarioTodo(UsuarioServiceImpl.java:35)

at `com.solmit.service.impl.UsuarioServiceImpl.listarUsuarioTodo(UsuarioServiceImpl.java:35)`  debería ser un link.

Cuando lo hago de manera  `System.out.println("\tat xxx")` en un metodo main si sale el link uso netbeans 8.1 logger lombok

Comment: Por favor agrega la versión de netbeans a tu pregunta

Comment: el netbeans 8.1 @Ruslan López

Comment: el logger que usas de que librería viene? es el por defecto de Java?  `@Log` en lombok o algún otro como `@SL4J`

Comment: proviene de Lombok Log4j2

Comment: la naturaleza de tu proyecto es maven?

Comment: si gracias halle el problema era que faltaba ponerle %msg%n

Answer (score 0):

Para que salga un link debes de imprimir con el formato:

```
NombreDeClase.NombreDeMétodo(NombreDeFicheroFuente:NúmeroDeLínea)
```

Por ejemplo usando el Logger por defecto:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {
    final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackTraceElement s = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1];
        log.info(s.getClassName()+"."+s.getMethodName()+"("+s.getFileName()+":"+s.getLineNumber()+")");
    }
}
```

Si con ello no te funciona, tal vez necesites agregar el jar del código fuente al classpath mientras corre tu programa.

Comment: cuando hago de agregar el jar del código, por que tu ejemplo sale como un texto normal